# LC3 Multiplication

Tags: lc3

So I have an LC3 coding assignment where we have to implement and test user subroutines for input and output of unsigned integers in decimal format. Now for our input we have to do a sequence of keystrokes to construct a single integer value by applying a Repeated Multiplication algorithm, which would be multiplication by 10 via 4 additions. I am not really understanding this concept of multiplication by 4 additions. Could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is number you want to multiply by `10`

```
a = x+x = 2x
b = a+a = 4x
c = b+b = 8x
d = a+c = 10x
```

Answer (score 0):

If your value is in `R1` you can try the following:

```
ADD R2, R1, R1  ;Value = Value x 10
ADD R4, R2, R2
ADD R1, R4, R4
ADD R1, R1, R2
```